# Easiest way of compare classes of two branch

Tags: java, git, svn, version-control, git-merge

We created two branches and one developers group committed to master branch and another developer groups committed to development branch. We developed different requirements in two branches in last 2 months and now we want to merge these two branches. We are using SVN but it is not easy to merge these classes, because same class in two branches are changed several times and it's very complicated to merge now. What is the easiest way to merge these two branches? Branch history is not important for us. We can use git tools also, or visual tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to confuse merging-as-joining-histories
and merging-as-reconciling-changes.
These two most of the time are done at the same time — when one performs
a merge operation using their VCS, — and that's why they're not usually
being mentally distinguished in one's mind.

But in fact, they are distinct and you can use this to your advantage:

1. Run a normal merge operation using your VCS.

   You will have conflicts. That's inevitable and is okay.
2. Have the conflicts in the offending file resolved by using
   *either* of the both sides of the merge.

   Something like `svn checkout --theirs ^path/to/that/file.java`
3. Take both versions of the *class implementation* and come up with
   another one which reconciles them both in a sensible way (code-wise).
4. Update the file with the implementation. Run tests to ensure it
   works as expected.
5. Commit.

Answer (score 0):

Generally that is why we must pull changes frequently so that that our code is always up-to-date with that of the masters. In your case, you will have to merge the changes manually.

If you'd like to incrementally apply the changes done in your branch on top of master, do a [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Like,

```
git checkout your_branch
git rebase -i master
```

This will allow you to apply your commits in chronological order, so you'd have merge the change commit by commit..thus decreasing the number of conflicts.